# Print lines whose 1st and 4th column differ

Tags: shell, search, grep, multiple-columns

I have a file with a bunch of lines of this form:

```
12 AAA 423 12 BBB beta^11 + 3*beta^10
18 AAA 1509 18 BBB -2*beta^17 - beta^16
18 AAA 781 12 BBB beta^16 - 5*beta^15
```

Now I would like to print only lines where the 1st and the 4th column differ (the columns are space-separated) (the values `AAA` and `BBB` are fixed). I know I can do that by getting all possible values in the first column and then use:

```
for i in $values; do
  cat file.txt | grep "^$i" | grep -v " $i BBB"
done
```

However, this runs through the file as many times as how many different values appear in the first column. Is there a way how to do that simply in one pass only? I think I can do the comparison, my main problem is that I have no idea how to extract the space-separated columns.

Comment: Note that `cat file.txt | grep "^$i"` can be compacted into `grep "^$i" file.txt`.

Comment: @fedorqui Thanks for pointing it out, I know, but since I need two consecutive `grep`s anywas, I prefer to pipe them both ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is something quite straight forward for `awk`:

```
awk '$1 != $4' file
```

With `awk`, you refer to the first field with `$1`, the second with `$2` and so on. This way, you can compare the first and the forth with `$1 != $4`. If this is true (that is, `$1` and `$4` differ), `awk` performs its default action: print the current line.

For your sample input, this works:

```
$ awk '$1 != $4' file
18 AAA 781 12 BBB beta^16 - 5*beta^15
```

Note you can define a different field separator with `-v FS="..."`. This way, you can tell `awk` that your lines contain fields tab / comma / ... separated. All together it would be like this: `awk -v FS="\t" '$1 != $4' file`.

Comment: I can only say: wow! I really should learn `awk` properly. I thought it could be used, but I didn't think it's as simple. I'll accept once I can ;)

Comment: Nice to read this :) `awk` is quite fast to learn and provides good results in small code. I would recommend you to go through this interesting tutorial: [Idiomatic awk](http://backreference.org/2010/02/10/idiomatic-awk/). It covers some handy cases. Cheers!

Comment: Gawk at the power of awk. +1 although a cleaner way to set the field separator is to use the `-F` flag directly rather than to set the variable with the `-v` option. `awk -F'\t' '$1 != $4'` :)